# What is <<- in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

[From the Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols:](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)

Author is trying to show a simplified implementation of the attr_writer method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def make_me_a_setter(thename)
    eval <<-SETTERDONE         # <----- Here
    def #{thename}(myarg)
        @#{thename} = myarg
    end
    SETTERDONE
end

class Example
    make_me_a_setter :symboll
    make_me_a_setter "stringg"

    def show_symboll
        puts @symboll
    end

    def show_stringg
        puts @stringg
    end
end

example = Example.new
example.symboll("ITS A SYMBOL")
example.stringg("ITS A STRING")
example.show_symboll
example.show_stringg
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to learn a language looking at things that were written 8 years ago =)

Comment: This sort of thing can be searched for at http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3C%3C-

Comment: When you insert a link into any page, use some meaningful text for the link-text. "From this:" isn't meaningful. Instead, use something like: "From '[The Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)':". See "[Don't use "click here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere) and "[6.1 Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" from the W3's "HTML Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0".

Comment: @Pigueiras I should get rid of my Blue Book :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a *heredoc*. From the "[Here Documents](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)" documentation:

> If you are writing a large block of text you may use a “here document”
>   or “heredoc”:
>
> ```
> expected_result = <<HEREDOC
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
> HEREDOC
> ```
>
> The heredoc starts on the line following `<<HEREDOC` and ends with the
>   next line that starts with `HEREDOC`. The result includes the ending
>   newline.

Comment: And the dash between `<<` and the delimiter token means to ignore whitespace on the same line as the end token.

Comment: It allows you to indent the closing modifier.

Answer (score 2):

It's a multi line string. The code evaluates code embedded inside string. More on multi line strings:

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html

P.S. Using eval is not recommended, alternatives - yield, instance_eval, class_eval.

Comment: `SETTERDONE` can be any string.